# Neo4j CSV Import with multiple Where

Tags: neo4j

So I am importing a rather robust CSV with tons of information in it. Rather than slicing it and reduplicating a lot of data and cleansing does Neo4j support a where clause in a multiple way for instance:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///registryDump.csv' AS line
WITH line
WHERE line[25] IS NOT NULL
MERGE (u:User {name: line[25]})
ON CREATE SET u.source = "Registry", u.type = "Owner"
```

Than additionally add another:

```
WHERE line[12] IS NOT NULL
MERGE (u:User {name: line[12]})
ON CREATE SET u.source = "Registry", u.type = "Steward"
```

Making a much larger clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `CASE` and `FOREACH`:

```
WITH [0,1,null,3] as line
FOREACH(NULL IN CASE WHEN line[0]=0 THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (U:User{name:0})
  ON CREATE SET U.source = "Registry", U.type = "Steward"
)
FOREACH(NULL IN CASE WHEN line[1]<1 THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (U:User{name:1})
)
FOREACH(NULL IN CASE WHEN line[2] IS NOT NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (U:User{name:line[2]})
)
FOREACH(NULL  IN CASE WHEN line[3] IS NOT NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (U:User{name:line[3]})
)
```

Taken from [Mark Needham. Neo4j: LOAD CSV – Handling empty columns](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/08/22/neo4j-load-csv-handling-empty-columns/)